# How to use EOF to read all data from file

Tags: c, file-io, eof

I'm learning about file i/o in C language and I wrote this program that reads a file, and then for every even number found, it has to print `*` to the screen.

My problem is that my program keeps printing `*` forever.

I have tried different ways,some from this website, but I can't seem to understand how to read until end of a text file using EOF.

I want to learn how to read a text file until the end of the file please.
How do I read until the end of a text file? EOF in C.

```
int main(void)
 {

     int num;
     FILE *ifp;

     ifp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r" );

     if(ifp == NULL)
     {
         exit(1);
     }

     do
     {
         fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num);       

            if(num%2 == 0)

                {
                printf("*\n");
                }
        } while(num != EOF);


    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are printing ```*``` for the even number though.

Comment: @Lucas sorry about that! I have fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the result of the `scanf`

```
     do
     {
         int result;
         result = fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num);       
         if(result == EOF) break;

         if(result != 1) 
         {
             printf("scanf error\n");
             break;
         }
         if(num%2 == 0)
         {
              printf("*\n");
         }
      } while(1);
```

Comment: hey! thx, I made those changes, and now is not printing `*`. I checked with he debugger and noticed that goes into the `scanf error` in line 25

Comment: so you have the problem with your file. It fails to scan. ***Always*** check the result of any I/O operation

Answer (score 0):

It's doing this because `while(num != EOF)` is testing whether `int num`, the number read from the file, is `EOF`, rather than whether the end of file has been reached.

<del>To test whether the EOF flag has been set on `FILE *ifp`, use `while(!feof(ifp))` instead.</del>

Comment: Hey! thank you for your help. Should I do while loop or add it tho the end of the do-while loop? thx

Comment: NO NO NO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Yes, I strongly suggest you to read that post, which is linked by P_J_

Comment: @P__J__ I wasn't considering concurrency, and I will edit my post to reflect that what I suggested was not best practice. However, the first part of what I said is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should try `while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
 {

     int num;
     FILE *ifp;

     ifp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r" );

     if(ifp == NULL)
     {
         perror("Read");
         exit(1);
     }

     while(fscanf(ifp, "%d ", &num) != EOF)
     {

         if(num % 2 != 0) // For every odd number.

                {
                printf("*\n");
                }
     }
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
while (!feof(ifp)) {
   if (fscanf(ifp, "%d ", &num) > 0) {
      if(num % 2 != 0) // For every odd number.
                {
                printf("*\n");
                }
   }
}
```